# Stone-Cech extension of a function satisfying $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$?

Tags: general-topology, functions, compactness, functional-equations, compactification

Suppose $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfies the equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$. Such a function may not be continuous, but is there still a way to extend it to a mapping from $\beta\mathbb R$ to $\beta\mathbb R$?

I am asking because I don't know much about how to extend non-continuous functions, but this function seems nice enough that maybe something will work.

Comment: What sort of properties would you want the extension to have?

Comment: What are you asking for property of such $\beta f$ ? Obviously it cannot be continous since it restriction will not necessarly be continous. So what property do you want ?

Comment: What about the identity function or the $0$ function? Both satisfy $f(x + y)= f(x) + f(y)$.

Comment: @OlesWohnzimmer But I want a general way of extending.  

As for properties maybe $\beta f$ can satisfy the same equation?  Where $p+q=\{A+B:A\in p,B\in q\}$?

Comment: @ForeverMozart Sorry..what is this notation $\beta \mathbb R$ ?Compacatification?

Comment: I don't understand the definition of $p+q$ you wrote: what do you mean by $A\in p$?  Are you thinking of points of $\beta\mathbb{R}$ as certain filters?  If so, there is no reason to think that your formula for $p+q$ would describe an element of $\beta\mathbb{R}$.  In fact, I don't believe there's any natural way to extend the operation $+$ to $\beta\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In any case, it seems extremely likely to me that the answer to your question is simply "no"--the topological structure of $\mathbb{R}$ and the additive structure are only very weakly related, so it's very unreasonable to expect to be able to relate them in a way like this.  But I can't prove a statement like this without a concrete notion of what properties you might hope the extension to have.

Comment: AFAIK addition of ultrafilters is usually defined in a different way, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification#Addition_on_the_Stone.E2.80.93.C4.8Cech_compactification_of_the_naturals).(link to [recent revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification&oldid=724921806#Addition_on_the_Stone.E2.80.93.C4.8Cech_compactification_of_the_naturals).) This works Stone-Čech compactification $\beta S$ of a **discrete space** $S$. From any semigroup $(S,+)$ you get a semigroup $(\beta S,+)$ in this way.